# Missing required UserInfo Uri in UserInfoEndpoint for Client Registration

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am facing with below error while accessing to api within OAuth2.0 credentials.

The examples on Internet containing user-info-uri credential, but I have only authorization-uri and token-uri. How can I successfully connect without user-info-uri ?

Authorization screen is successfully opened, but after that the error is shown:

### [missing_user_info_uri] Missing required UserInfo Uri in UserInfoEndpoint for Client Registration: aa-client-1

---

My application.yml like this :

> spring:
>    security:
>
> > oauth2:
> >
> > > ```
> > > client:
> > >    registration:
> > >      aa-client-1:
> > >       client-id: XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXX
> > >         client-secret: XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXX
> > >         provider: A
> > >         scope: A:scope
> > >         authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
> > >         redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login
> > >     provider: 
> > >       A:
> > >         authorization-uri: https://someurls/authorize
> > >         token-uri: https://someurl/token
> > > ```

I want to login the API without user-info-uri.

Comment: Could you add your @Configuration class?

Comment: I have no configuration class, just Application and Controller class.

Comment: Spring Security for OAuth 2 requires the user-info-uri. It uses it to get the username to build the Principal: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4992

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you must provide an `user-info-uri` if your grant type is `authorization_code`.
See [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5659#issuecomment-412981657) and [Spring Security Source Code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/65b9dbf031fddff61fb8e13baa67d55131c99055/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/userinfo/OidcUserService.java#L157).
Perhaps [this workaround](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5659#issuecomment-1079728377) may also applicable to your context.